# Automapping nested classes with one DTO

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0, .net-core-3.0

So i'm building a webapp with some friends where i will create the backend code for it. I have got several models but only one model is coming in from the httppost.

so what i have got for incoming http post:

```
    public class LanpartyDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<DateTime, IList<string>> UsersAvailableForDate { get; set; }

}

public class Lanparty
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid  AvailablityId{ get; set; }

    public IList<Availability> AvailableUsers { get; set; }
}


public class Availability
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string DateAvailable { get; set; }

    public IList<string> Name { get; set; }

}

 public AutoMapping()
    {
        CreateMap<Lanparty, LanpartyDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.UsersAvailableForDate, m => m.MapFrom(src => src.AvailableUsers.ToDictionary(k=>k.DateAvailable, v=>v.Name.ToList())));



    }
```

So can I map one dto with multiple nested classes? so far i guess not coz i'm getting a map exception and looking here and on google it's possible if i would make a availabilitydto aswell but i see no use of that? 
So what's my best option try to change the frontend code so i can change my dto? or just create mapping code myself since this is for one class its not difficult?

Comment: Can you share the code of your AutoMapper Profile? And also why aren't you following the naimg conventions? One of the property names stars with the capital letter and the other with the lowercase.

Comment: @gleb because i typed my code directly in here to create a simple example i didn't copy my code

Comment: @gleb i have edited with the code and automapping i have

Comment: Use an AvailabilityDTO and if you want to keep that `Dictionary<DateTime, IList<string>> UsersAvailableForDate` just build it directly in a getter only property.

Comment: so if i understand right i have to make another mapping from availability to availabilitydto and my dictionary set to get only?

Comment: Am I missing something or what? Each of your Lanparty has FK to AvailabilityId. So if we're speaking in terms of OOP, your Lanparty owns one Availability which is basically a user. And how's Availability with one Date and one Name could be transformed into a collection of these?

Comment: hold on I'll try to explain so each lanparty has a dictionary  with a list of user that are available some date. so it is basically a list in a list. so if I have a lanparty and a nested class which holds lanparty id with datetime and a userid i guess that will do. right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping you want would look like this:

```
CreateMap<Lanparty, LanpartyDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UsersAvailableForDate,
        m => m.MapFrom(src => src.AvailableUsers.ToDictionary(k => k.DateAvailable, v => v.Name)));

CreateMap<LanpartyDto, Lanparty>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.AvailableUsers,
        m => m.MapFrom(src => src.UsersAvailableForDate.Select(u => new Availability { DateAvailable = u.Key, Name = u.Value })));
```

I allowed myself to change Availability.DateAvailable property type to DateTime as I don't quite understand why you're using string there. But if you want it to be a string, just add `ToString()` to the `u.Key` part.

Comment: I guess this can do the trick thx for this example i'll try this evening what i can do with this

Comment: @TechnologyResearcher sure thing. You can ask me in the commets section of any problems you might face.

Comment: this part is working can you help me with the other way around, when the source is dictionary and the destination is the nested class?

Comment: @TechnologyResearcher It would be appreciated if you'd given an example of the classes. And the properties you need to map.

Comment: ethe answer you have given, but the other way around? lanpartyDto to lanparty so you would go from the dictionary to nested class?

Comment: @TechnologyResearcher I am sorry for the late reply. I don't quite understand. Your `AvailableUsers` property inside `Lanparty` is a sole object. There's no list. So how am I supposed to map it with a dictionary. There's something missing here, obviously.

Comment: Ow yes i see, i have some changed made to the model the availability is a list to, i'll edit my question when I get home.

Comment: i have changed my models to what they are now. so the answer you gave me i already implemented as you can see in the automapper, I need to same but the other way around, from LanpartyDto to Lanparty, because my lanpartydto is my incomping httppost and lanparty and availability will be my database

Comment: @Technology Researcher I've modified the answer. But there are few things I don't understand. Why would you use a string for `Availability.DateAvailable` property and what's the point of `AvailablityId` as well as `Date` inside `Lanparty`, as these are inside `Availability`?

Comment: it could be a datetime the string i tested it for different datetime formats, because datetime in lanparty is the exact date when the lanparty will be initiated, the datetime in availability is the list of useres that are available on a specific date, this will be used to calculated the lanparty date when all members will be free, like a calendar or a doodle

Comment: wauw thankx man, just tested it and worked perfectly that awesome i didn't knew how to do it with automapper and didn't find any good documentation on it on google. many thx learned something new today haha

Comment: @TechnologyResearcher you're welcome. I'm happy to help